# Can i RedirectToAction to another controller passing an id route in a postmethode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I would like to "RedirectToAction" to another controller with parameters in a postmethod.

i have tried several things but nothing works, the route parameter does not show up in the url.

```
 return RedirectToAction("Details", "Categorie", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id }));
 return RedirectToAction("Details", "Categorie", eigenschap.CategorieID);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_RedirectToAction_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) that accepts an `object`, which creates the route values based on property names / values.

If you have a route value of `CategorieID`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Categorie", new { eigenschap.CategorieID });
```

Or if your route value is `id`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Categorie", new { id = eigenschap.CategorieID });
```